# Javascript error: "is not a function"

Tags: javascript

Base pairs are a pair of AT and CG. I'm trying to match the missing element to the provided character and return the results as a 2d array.

When I used the method below, it works fine.

```
 function pair(str) {
     str.split("");
    //convert the string into an array
     var newArray = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
       var subArray = [];
       switch (str[i]){
         case "G":
           subArray.push("G", "C");
           break;
         case "C":
          subArray.push("C", "G");
           break;
         case "A":
           subArray.push("A", "T");
           break;
         case "T":
           subArray.push("T", "A");
           break;
       }
       newArray.push(subArray);
     }

      return newArray;
    }

    pair("GCG");
    //[["G", "C"], ["C", "G"], ["G", "C"]]
```

However, when I tried to change the method from `push()` to `splice()`as below, it doesn't work.

```
function pair(str) {

  str.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
   var subArray = [];
   switch (str[i]){
     case "G":
       subArray.push("G", "C");
       break;
     case "C":
      subArray.push("C", "G");
       break;
     case "A":
       subArray.push("A", "T");
       break;
     case "T":
       subArray.push("T", "A");
       break;
   }
   str.splice(i, 1, subArray);
  }
  return str;

}

pair("GCG");
//ERROR:"str.splice is not a function"
```

At first I thought the reason why this method failed is that we can't set the third parameter in `splice()`to be an array. So I tried this:

```
["G", "C", "G"].splice(0,1,["G","C"])   //["G"]
```

Looks like it works.

Can anyone show me where am I wrong, please?

Comment: Are you using iframes or tab pages?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari lol, yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`string.split()` function does not mutate itself.** It returns an array and leave itself as unchanged as string. Looks like you want to split your `str` into individual characters from this line of code `str.split("")` and process. So see this code below:

```
function pair(str) {

    var tokens = str.split("");
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
        var subArray = [];
        switch (tokens[i]){
         case "G":
              subArray.push("G", "C");
               break;
         case "C":
              subArray.push("C", "G");
               break;
         case "A":
               subArray.push("A", "T");
       break;
         case "T":
               subArray.push("T", "A");
               break;
       }
       tokens.splice(i, 1, subArray);
  }
  return str; // Not sure if you intend to return original str or not
              // So please see my note below:
}
```

I'm not sure at the bottom part of your code whether you indeed want to return the string.

*NOTE:* If you want to append those characters in `subArray` back to `str` and return, you can do this:

```
return tokens.concat(subArray).join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str.splice(i, 1, subArray);
```

str is string.

.splice() method of Array

Check your logic ( or typo possible there should be subArray )

```
subArray.splice(i, 1, subArray);
```

Comment: Thanks !!! The split() method returns a new array without change the original string. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.split` doesn't change the string into an array, it returns an array. So you can do this `str = str.split('');`

Your original function worked because you can access strings with `[]` as well.